# Float image to the top right in multi-line text

Tags: css, css-float

I want the icon to stay at the top right. I have tried many things but nothing seems to work. It is only an issue when the text is really long or on a smaller device.

```css
.container {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}
.image-right {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h3>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua 
    <span class="image-right">
      <img style="width:13px; height:13px" src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/2354/dusseldorf/32/plus.png">
    </span>
  </h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Try  placing the image above the text. here is the link I tried. https://jsfiddle.net/utjd3u71/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the image before the text inside the h3 tag. As it says on http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp,

> Elements after a floating element will flow around it.

```html
<style>
.container{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
}

.image-right  {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
}
</style>
</head>


<div class="container">
<h3>
  <img style="width:13px; height:13px" src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/2354/dusseldorf/32/plus.png"
      class="image-right">

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua 


</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! That was it. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer. You should use `position: absolute;`

```css
.container{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
}

.container h3 {
  position: relative;
}

.image-right  {
    float: right;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h3>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua 
    <span class="image-right">
      <img style="width:13px; height:13px" src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/2354/dusseldorf/32/plus.png">
    </span>
  </h3>
</div>
```

Comment: This won't float the image though - if the text happens to overlap the image, it won't float around, it will overlap.